# How to determine if any arrays in an object has an entry

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

This is unlike most questions, which concern arrays of objects, not objects of arrays.  I have a data structure such as the following, and I need to determine if any of the arrays contained by the object contain any values.

All I need is true/false if *any* of the arrays has at least one value.  Please also consider effort in my (self-)answer.

```
let pendingAdditions = {
  hospitals: ['Silencio Hospital','St Judes'],
  licenses: ['poe-tic license'],
  medschools: []
}
```

Comment: I would look into using lodash for this as they have an _.isEmpty method that would help you most likely.

Comment: What is the actual outcome? What do you want the final result to be? That is unclear in your question.

Comment: @epascarello Maybe see my own answer; I just need true or false.  You are right though, I can make my question more clear

Comment: @MattE I've used `_.isEmpty` a lot but maybe I wasn't clear, as the object is always going to begin with empty arrays for hospitals/licenses/medschools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found nothing upon googling, maybe that is because the answer is as simple as:

```
let somePendingAdditions = Object.values(pendingAdditions).some(arr => arr.length);
```

However there is an alternative solution which is probably not as performant but also has interesting pitfalls possibly worth noting:

```
somePendingAdditions = 
    Boolean(Array.prototype.concat.apply([], Object.values(pendingAdditions)).length);
```

The pitfall(s) have to do with passing the correct first argument to apply.  Ordinarily this is done with `{}` or `null`, but in the first case `{}` will be an entry in the resulting array; in the case of passing `null` an error results.

Answer (score 2):

How about `Object.values` with `flat` and `includes`.

```js
// Check if Object has value as arrays and atleast one value is there.
const hasAnyEntry = (items) => Object.values(items).flat().length > 0;

const pendingAdditions = {
  hospitals: ['Silencio Hospital','St Judes'],
  licenses: ['poe-tic license'],
  medschools: []
}
console.log(hasAnyEntry(pendingAdditions));
console.log(hasAnyEntry({}));


// Check if given entry is exist in Object value arrays
const hasEntry = (items, entry) => Object.values(items).flat().includes(entry);

console.log(hasEntry(pendingAdditions, 'St Judes'));
console.log(hasEntry(pendingAdditions, 'Blah'));
```

Comment: I wondered if there was a solution using `flat`. I do need to work on clarifying my question, I just need to know if any of the arrays contain any value whatsoever, not a particular value.

Comment: @Dexygen, Oh ok got it. I just updated the answer. If we just need check for any value `hasAnyEntry` will work.